# Как изменить цвет текста в select в зависимости от выбранного option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

т.е. selected по умолчанию стоит одним цветом, а выбранные пункты другим в самом select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример как можно это сделать с помощью `jQuery`. У каждого `option` добавил атрибут `data-color` в котором записал цвет. Задал обработчик для `select` `onchage`, и при смене `option` добавил цвет текста для `select`, взятый из текущего `option`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').on('change',function(){
    $(this).css({color: $(this).find('option:selected').data('color')});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name"test">
  <option value="chage color" data-color="black">change color</option>
  <option value="red" data-color="red">red</option>
  <option value="green" data-color="green">green</option>
  <option value="blue" data-color="blue">blue</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот небольшая демонстрация со сменой цвета и текста из списка:

```html
 <select class="change_color">
  <option value="">Выберите цвет</option>
  <option value="green">Привет , я зеленый цвет</option>
  <option value="blue">Привет , я синий цвет</option>
  <option value="red">Привет , я красный цвет</option>
  <option value="yellow">Привет , я желтый цвет</option>
 </select>

 <h1 class='show_text'>Текст по умолчанию</h1>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".change_color").on('change',function(e)
  {
   var color = $(this).val();
   var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
   
   
   $(this).css('color',color);
   $('.show_text').css('color',color);
   $('.show_text').text(text);
  });
 });
 </script>
```